# has_many through but with unique source and multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

- As a user, I can add my favorite book to my book list.
- Another user adds the same book to their book list.
- There should only be one instance of the book in the database but 2 user/book associations.

  ```
  class User
    has_many :bookReferences
    has_many :books, through: :bookReferences

  class Book
    validates_uniqueness_of :title
    has_many :bookReferences
    has_many :users, through: :bookReferences

  class BookReference
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :book
  ```

**The first problem, is that if the book is already in the system, the bookReference is not created for the second user because the book isn't unique.**

So, if the book is already in the system, I want to just create the association record in the bookReference table.

**The second problem, when a user deletes a book, I only want it to delete the reference to the book unless they are the only user referencing that book.**

Basically, this is complete overview of the usage I'm trying to achieve:

```
    user1.books.first
      => id: 1, title: "Moby Dick"
    user2.books.first
      => id: 1, title: "Moby Dick"
    books.all
      => id: 1, title: "Moby Dick"


    user1.books.first.destroy
    user1.books.first
      => nil
    books.all
      => id: 1, title: "Moby Dick"
    user2.books.first
      => id: 1, title: "Moby Dick"
    user2.books.first.destroy
      => nil
    books.all
      => nil
```

***UPDATE***

Based on these answers, perhaps I wasn't very clear. Let me try again...
The book controller, has a basic CRUD create method which:

```
    def create
      current_user.books.create(name: params[:book][:title])
```

With the way the has_many through association is setup currently, the book will only be created if it is unique. If it's already in the system, it will return false. What I WANT it to do is create the association with the existing book as if it was a new record. This is what I am currently doing in my application to accomplish this but it feels wrong:

```
   def create
     book = Book.where(name: params[:book][:title]).first_or_create!
     BookReference.where(book_id: book.id, user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create!
```

Then the second problem is when a user removes a book from their account. Doing the traditional CRUD destroy will remove it from all accounts:

```
    def destroy
      book = current_user.books.find(params[:id])
      book.destroy
```

So to get around this, I'm currently doing the following. Again though, this doesn't feel "right":

```
    def destroy
      book = current_user.books.find(params[:id])
      # if book was unique to user
      if BookReference.where(book_id: book.id).count == 1
        # remove book from system
        book.destroy  
      else
        # remove book reference but not book
        current_user.books.delete(book)
      end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still kinda new to rails as well, but this is what I came up with.

```
book = user1.books.first
if book.users.size > 1 
  user1.books.first.destroy
else
  book.destroy 
end
# in order to delete the book's dependency, you will need
class Book
has_many :bookReferences, :dependent => :destroy
```

Hope this helps.

NOTE:
When you have a model named like `BookReference`, you refer the model as `:book_reference`
In your case, you need to change to

```
class User
  has_many :book_references
  has_many :books, through: :book_references

class Book
  validates_uniqueness_of :title
  has_many :book_references
  has_many :users, through: :book_references

class BookReference
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book
```

UPDATE:

Since you want the new book created when it's not present in the database, one rails method you could take advantage of is `Book.find_or_create()`. I'm not going into the details but I feel like later on you would want an autocomplete feature to look up the books.
Take a look at this railscast on [Autocomplete](http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association). Ryan Bates did a great job on setting up the autocomplete and create new entry if it's not found, which is what you are looking for.

Furthermore, if you need an easier way to allow users to add multiple books, here's another railscast that teaches you about [Token Fields](http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields)

Comment: This is a way to handle deleting, but it doesn't cover the actual association itself. With a typical has_many through association, each model get's a unique id. If I add validation for uniqueness, I can't even add a duplicate book. So before even worrying about how to delete, I need to know how to crate an association like this.

Comment: @Duncan I thought the question is about handling deletion. What association are you referring to? I don't quite understand.

Comment: @Duncan I suggest you to watch [this video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/47-two-many-to-many) first. Seems like you aren't very clear about the association between the models.

Comment: How am I not very clear on associations exactly? Yes, I've seen that video before. Apart from your book_reference name change, what are you suggesting I don't understand?

Comment: like iRichLau stated in his answer, that's one way to add existing books for a user into `book_references`. Other ways like creating CRUD views and controller for `BookReference` can be used to look up `book_id` and `user_id` for you to create the association. If you used `Scaffold` to generate `BookReference`, then it's already set up.

Comment: Please see question update. I tried to be as clear as possible.

Comment: Correct on seeing down the road to my next task, autocomplete. However, that looks like a very dated approach to take and wouldn't change my current problem with the models. On the topic of model creation, any info on the best method? i.e. find_or_create, find_or_create_by_name, first_or_create etc as it seems like the way I'm currently going is the "right" way..:(

Answer (score 0):

rails automatically creates the bookreference for you when you use the has_many through association.

has many through creates a "hidden column" called :book_ids in your user model

so in your form that you want to "save" a book to a user you would use

```
<%= form_for (@user) do |f| %>
.
.
.
<%= f.label :book_ids %>
<%= f.select :book_ids, Book.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {}, :multiple => true %>
```

your bookreference should be automatically populated and you can display it in the view. Edit and destroys are automatically done for you too. when you delete or edit it will be only the bookreference table.

if you want to know more about associations you can go to

http://api.rubyonrails.org/

and search for ActiveRecord::Associations

Comment: Maybe because you decided to use your own example instead of using the one I provided, but I don't see how this applies to my question. Sorry if I missed the point.

Comment: I used your example with books. Do you understand that when you create the has many through association, your bookreference table is where you join the user and the book. I don't know what action you created so that you can associate the user and the book.

Comment: is BookReference your booklist? did you create a controller and form for a user to add books to your booklist? what data is in your bookreference model? user_id and book_id?

Comment: also every time you create an association you do not create a new book. when you create a bookreference it will create the association between the user and the book by saving their id's into bookreference.